# Having trouble creating VMWare image from physical machine - memory being restricted to 880MB

Tags: vmware-converter

I have an old laptop I'm trying to create a VM image from.  I'm using the latest version of the VMware Converter app.

The machine is an Intel Core Duo with 1GB of RAM running WinXP Pro.

When I get to the "View/Edit Options" step in VMWare Converter there's a warning next to Memory.  The warning states:

> The memory allocated for the destination machine has been set to the maximum supported for the guest operating system by the target host.  The allocated memory is less than the source memory setting.

It shows that the maximum amount of memory I can allocate is 880MB.

What does this error mean?  Why would the converter be restricting me to 880MB of RAM?  I know VMWare can handle more than that, as can WinXP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't allocate more then 70% of physical memory to a virtual machine. Virtual Machine managers will give a warning since this will not leave enough physical memory for the host machine to run.

Virtual Machines are only allocated physical memory.

PS: The 70% I can't confirm at the moment but this has been my experience with most virtual machine managers. Hyper-V allows 80% on HyperVisor but only 60% when running on a full version of Server 2008. Others only allow up to 50% for example.

In your case the VM itself will be created as if you will be running it on the same machine acting as host.

Edit: The VM can still be created using the specified memory size. It is a warning only that the virtual machine may not run on that particular machine. I am not sure if this has changed in the newer VMWare converter.

Comment: That means it's calculating the RAM based on the machine the converter is running on?  That seems kind of dumb, since the converter is converting the local machine.

Comment: The converter has no idea what host your planning to run the machine on, therefore it will use what is available. This is by design.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Now to figure out why the VM image it created bluescreens when windows starts to load...

Comment: That is an issue with the drivers and P2V. I would suggest google since there isn't one specific fix, it is a trail and error problem unfortunately. Remember Windows is being loaded on a complete new set of hardware.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of memory assigned to the VM can be changed later, but I think that you already figured it out :).

I solved the blue screen issues after converting a physical machine to a virtual one by changing the virtual disk adapter from IDE to SCSI.

HTH!

Comment: it wont' let me change the bus type of the drive.  But I think I can do that at conversion time.

Comment: You cannot change the adapter type, but you can remove the virtual disk and re-add it using the different adapter. IIRC, the converter ignores the actual adapter type you specify, leaving you with an IDE disk no matter what you choose.

Comment: I just re-converted the machine and told it to use SCSI.  That appears to have fixed the bluescreen.  Getting an error on boot still, but it's just some random app crashing and doesn't seem to be causing actual problems.